# Is there an "easy way" of adding custom UI to a Qt application when using QGraphicsView?

Tags: qt

I'm using QGraphicsView to show randomly generated polygons in a QGraphicsScene and it's all working fine and dandy, but now I want to add custom UI styling to my application and it's proving to be quite annoying to do everything by hand, while there are so many wonderful options out there like QtQuick. It is possible at all to use QtQuick or something like it together with a graphicsView?

Quick note:
I'm new to Qt so I might be missing something obvious here!

EDIT:
Added an image for clarification, I just want to modify the sliders and buttons to have a custom texture!

[image]

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com! - It depends on what you want your UI to look like. A sketch would greatly help to improve your question. Here are some hints, though: You can simply add widgets around your QGraphicsView into the same layout. If you're using QML, you can add your controls there. You can even overlay your view with widgets, although that's not ideal. You can use `QGraphicsWidget` to host QWidget descendants in a QGraphicsScene (although that tends to get a bit ugly).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I've added an image for clarification. I want to modify the sliders etc. on the left-hand side to have a custom texture! If I understood correctly, you're advising me to put those into a separate widget and edit that widget using QML / QtQuick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `QQuickWidget` class to embed a QML view in a Qt widgets.

For example:

```
// main.qml
Item {
    id: main
    visible: true
    width: 200

    Column {
        ComboBox {
            model: ["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3"]
        }

        Slider {
        }
        Slider {
        }
        Slider {
        }
    }
}
```

```
// main.cpp
#include <QQuickWidget>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    QApplication app(argc, argv);


    QQuickWidget *view = new QQuickWidget;
    view->setSource(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    QWidget* widget = new QWidget();
    QHBoxLayout* layout = new QHBoxLayout(widget);
    layout->addWidget(view);
    layout->addWidget(new QLabel("A classic widget"));

    widget->show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Romha Korev's answer is correct when you want to use QML for that part of the UI.

Another option for styling is by using stylesheets. See the [Qt stylesheet reference](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet.html)

If it's cumbersome for you to setup the widgets in code, try [Qt Designer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtdesigner-manual.html).

I use these 2 tools for making styled UI apps with Qt, and find it very handy